# Visual Studio 2017: Run tests with Startup Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, automated-tests

I have a solution containing a few projects, three of which startup when hitting the `Start` button, which are integral to the operation of the program. I have some tests, which have been found by Visual Studio and are inside the `Test Explorer` panel.

The question is: When I hit the `Run All` button inside the `Test Explorer` panel, how can I tell Visual Studio to startup the same projects as when I hit the `Start` button?

The only way I can see it being done is by using a `*.testsettings`file to use a Setup script that will run the projects, but it just feels like a dirty way of doing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The tests should be isolated and you should not have dependencies on executables in order to test stuff.

Comment: @JuanR I can see the need to do this for system or integration tests.  If they require the product to be running in order to test them.  The test explorer runs more than just unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Open two visual studio apps, one for running your three projects and the other for running the tests. But I think only functional/integration tests need to test the executions which are running currently.

Answer (score 0):

The way I have accomplished this in the past for system tests that need the main executable running is to leverage the [`Assembly Initialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx) in the test project and have it start the required exe.

We have a build setup that puts all of our debug output into a common location, so we can find the appropriate exe because it is in the same path as the test assembly.

```
[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext context)
{
    // Launch the exe here.
}
```